# Bluetooth: hci0: unexpected event for opcode 0x0000 on Startup

Tags: linux-mint, boot, bluetooth

I (a linux noob) have installed linux mint 20.3 (Una) on an older fujitsu laptop and recently did some updates. Since then, I get an error message on boot:

> Bluetooth: hci0: unexpected event for opcode 0x0000

The system then asks for login/password and continues after successful login to the console window. The graphical interface, which is usually started, does not show up. What do I have to do to get to the graphical interface?

I tried the "startx" command. A black screens opens up with a mouse cursor, but nothing else happens.

**EDIT**
It seems I could overcome the error by using the command "sudo systemctl enable bluetooth". So the remaining question is how to get back to the graphical interface, because this is still not launched.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue -- without the login. What worked for me is:

- switch to another tty, and log in there
- clean installation files with apt autoremove
  then reboot

Hope it helps!

Answer (score -2):

I had same problem but to be frankly said , you should not use bluetooth (blueberry ) . I have already upgraded to linuxmint 21.1 ( still facing a few problems ) but when it was 20.3 , I manually installed blueman ( bluetooth manager ) , which comes by default in 21, by this command :
sudo apt install blueman
and it asks me to automatically start on startup .
I did uninstall bluetooth and problem solved after successful reboot ...
Enjoy ;)

Comment: It is unclear whether this answer says 1) don't use Bluetooth, 2) use `blueman`, 3) update uninstall Bluetooth, or 4) reboot to solve the problem.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).